# Ajax Control / RadEditor not working on a specific page

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlKit and RadEditor on couple pages, but the problem is Ajax Control and RadEditor are not working on a specific page.

A/B/C/X.aspx working

A/B/D/Y.aspx not working

I checked the web.config files under folder C and D, and they are exactly the same.
AjaxControlKit has been added to the global web.config file under folder A.

Thanks a lot,

Here is the error msg I got from Firebug

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - ....ase.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_AjaxScriptManager_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.51116.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3afd384f95-1b49-47cf-9b47-2fa2a921a36a%3a475a4ef5%3a5546a2b%3ad2e10b12%3aeffe2a26%3a37e2e5c9%3a1d3ed089%3a497ef277%3aa43b07eb%3a751cdd15%3adfad98a5%3a3cf12cf1%3aaddc6819%3a5a682656%3ac7029a2%3ae9e598a9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved.

ToolkitScriptManager. CombineScripts="false"